# Serious KDE graphical issues after waking up

Tags: drivers, graphics, kubuntu, kde, amd-graphics

On a fresh bootup/restart, the system works fine.   After waking up from sleep, though, there will be gradually increasing graphical glitches, until the entire graphic system freezes and becomes completely unresponsive. Examples:

- Menus will appear completely BLACK
- Save-File windows, pop-up windows, new Dolphin or Gwenview windows will be completely black.

The system will still be partially usable for a while, as these errors increase in frequency. I have tried toggling on/off the KDE Compositor, which will *clear* the BLACK window problem, but only temporarily for some applications.

Toggling on/off the Compositor will not delay or stop the total graphic session lockup. Without fail, eventually the graphical session will **completely lock-up** and **block any keyboard input**. (Unless I reboot before the lockup.)

Initially:
[image]

Then eventually:
[image]

And finally total graphics system lockup.

NOTE on Input: In KDE you can assign a shortcut hotkey sequence to do an no-prompts automatic KDE logout and reboot.When the whole graphics session freezes, even this key sequence will not work.

But this appears to be limited only to the graphical session: But the underlying system is still working. I can press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F2 for example, which will take me to an emergency console and I can run all my normal commands from there.

**System Info**:

I'm using Kubuntu 22.10, with backports enabled for the upcoming release of 23.04.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.6
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-38-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 62.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 580 Series
Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: X570 AORUS ELITE WIFI
System Version: -CF
```

I have tried turning on 'TearFree' but it does not seem to help.

My /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf file:

```
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier           "AMD"
    Driver               "amdgpu"
    Option "DRI"         "3"
    Option "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

This has persisted with my Kubuntu system since at least 22.04 and it is driving me crazy. I would appreciate ANY help, including possibly moving distros to something else!

(I would even be happy to know how to safely shutdown KDE from commandline! But I've never found anything that worked for modern KDE-5.)

Comment: I wonder if rather than being KDE related; it's related to the linux kernel & thus system related.  Have you booted a Kubuntu *lunar* system for example in *live* mode and seen if you have the same issue?  As *lunar* is using the 6.2 kernel (*where as 22.10 is 5.19, and 22.04 is 5.15 with GA or 5.19 with HWE*) I wonder if different. If it occurred running *lunar* you're off-topic here for support, but a bug report can be filed & that may contain clues for your support request on 22.10 (*kinetic*).  My thoughts.  If the GUI crashes, why not command shutdown using SysRq? (REISUO for off, REISUB)

Comment: @guiverc I've never heard of SysRq. I am hopeful that the never version of KDE (lunar) may fix this, but can you test a live CD using the system-suspend (sleep)? Like I said, I'm using backports as much as possible, but they do not seem to have fixed the problem despite version updates to many KDE components.

Comment: SysRq is a key on the keyboard (*though many modern keyboards no longer have it printed as it was printed on the front of the key, not keytop*).  If used (with ALT) the Linux kernel treats the following command as a command for the kernel, allowing you to bypass any stuck/dead UI & control your system directly; it only needs a real keyboard (no onscreen keyboard like phones/tablets! as they require working GUI). Search for "magic sysrq" on phone & scan the wikipedia article.. it's Linux so not limited to Ubuntu.  On some hardware you can suspend a *live* system (alas other boxes you cannot!)

Comment: Sometimes is good to disable acceleration and turning it back on. Use CTRL+MAYS+F12 to toggle it. Some glitches disappears. In my case sometimes windows don't refresh or menus leave ghost shadows after they disappear. This trick make them disappear. Also, I read there are some problems with the last 5.x kernels, I'm anxiously waiting for the 6.x release to hit my system.

Comment: @sanzante what is the MAYS key?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I mean SHIFT, MAYS is its name in Spanish, I crossed languages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Galaxy Book3 Pro with Kubuntu 23.04.

Turns out as @guiverc mentioned in the comments, upgrading the kernel version to 6.3 fixed the issue for me *(23.03 ships with a 6.2 Linux kernel)*.

You can follow [this](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/) or [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-update-kernel-ubuntu) guide to upgrade the kernel version.

Or upgrade to the latest version of Kubuntu, as it ships with a higher kernel than the one in 22.10

Hope this helps!